# Rename multiple files removing extra characters in Linux

Tags: linux

In a directory I have multiple files which starts with four digits. I used rename commands but I am lacking additional commands. I want to remove rest of the characters and leave with only four digits.

Following are file samples

```
0001tashi.jpg
0002tsering.jpg
0003dolma.jpg
0004samdupdorjee.jpg
```

I want to remove all characters other than first four digits as following.

```
0001.jpg
0002.jpg
0003.jpg
0004.jpg
```

How can we use linux command to rename multiple files?

Comment: You could use [`rename`](https://www.mankier.com/1/rename). (Note that there are two different utilities with that name, though.)

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to list the desired file names, pipe the list to `sed` to build a set of `mv` commands then pipe its output to a `bash` shell to run it:

```
 ls -1 *.jpg | sed 's/\(....\).*\.jpg/mv "&" \1.jpg/' | bash
```

Piece by piece:

- `ls -1 *.jpg` - list all files whose name end with `.jpg`
  `-1` ensures that `ls` puts one file name per line. It is not required in the final command; `ls` does this by itself when its output is not sent to the screen but to a file or a pipe but it is handy while developing the command line.
- `| sed 's/^\(....\).*\.jpg/mv "&" \1.jpg/'` - pipe the output of `ls` through a `sed` script that searches (`s///`) the lines that start with four characters (`....`) followed by zero or more character we don't care about (`.*`) followed by the JPEG file name termination (`\.jpg`) and replaces the matching part with `mv` followed by the entire matched string `&` and the first matching group (`\1`, it contains the substring that matches `\(....\)` i.e. the first 4 characters of the input line) and `.jpg`.
  This replaces each file name from input with a `mv` command that will rename it by keeping only its first 4 characters and the `.jpg` termination. The input file name is wrapped in quotes to allow file names that contain spaces.
- `| bash` - pass the `mv` commands to a new instance of the `bash` interpreter that will run them and exit.
  It is recommended to omit this part of the command line to check the correctness of the output generated by the `sed` command (dry run). If it looks fine to you then you can add this part to actually run the renames (the `mv` commands won't be displayed on the screen in this case but executed).